# Access the second item in Collection [Map]

Tags: javascript, object, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot, and fetching some messages. I got this object

```
//This parameters changue every time i fetch
Collection(3) [Map] {
  '848689862764789770' => Message {...
  }
  '848689552410804234' => Message {...
  }
  '848689534485004319' => Message {...
  }
```

I can access the first and third entry using `.first()` and `.last()`.

I've been trying to use `Object.keys()` but it returns `undefined`.

```
const mensajes = await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 3 });
                
console.log(mensajes[Object.keys(mensajes)[1]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Tip:**
`.first()` can take a parameter that will return the first x amount of entries you choose and will then convert the Collection into an Array. Do `.first(2)` - this will return the first 2 entries - and then access the 2nd element as you would with any other Array.

```
// Will return 2nd entry
<Collection>.first(2)[1]
```

**Suggested Solution:**
You can also call `.array()` on the Collection to directly convert it into an Array.

```
// Also returns 2nd entry
<Collection>.array()[1]
```

`<Collection>` *is a placeholder for your actual object*

Learn more about working with Collections in [This Guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html#array-like-methods)

Comment: bro, you are god, really really thanks you ;(

Answer (score 1):

DiscordJS's docs has [some information on this](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html#array-like-methods). You can transform this `Collection` utility class intro an array with a bunch of methods that exist for it, depending on what you need to access.

Then you can use the array, for example, to access the specific value.

> // For values. Array.from(collection.values());
>
> // For keys. Array.from(collection.keys());
>
> // For [key, value] pairs. Array.from(collection);